# Angular 2 Http, RxJS Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

**EDIT: I have solved this issue. Please see my answer below, as it may help someone. If you know a better answer, please post it! :)**

I am working on an [Angular 2 Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal) API cache, and have an ApiService like this:

```
import {Http} from '@angular/core';

export class ApiService {
    constructor(private http: Http, private cache: CacheService)
}

get(url) {
    if (cache_data) {
        //Create new observable from scratch
        return new Observable(sub => {
            sub.next(cache_data);
        });
    } else {
        //Use Angular 2's Http service, which creates an Observable for me
        return this.http.get(url)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(err => throw err);
    }
}
```

In another service, where I subscribe to it, I have:

```
import {ApiService} from './api/api.service';

export class ConsumerService {
    constructor(apiService: ApiService) {}
    let sub = this.apiService.get('www.example.com')
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
            sub.unsubscribe();
        })
}
```

If the requested data isn't in the cache and the server has to make an http request for it, the above code works perfectly. If data *is* in the cache, however, I get the following error: `Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined`
Undefined, of course, is referring to my variable `sub`.

My initial thought is that the type of Observable I'm creating in the cache vs Angular 2's Http observable are different, and therefore creating an error. I've tried testing this, but have no way to confirm it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why are you calling `unsubscribe` in the `next` block? Also there is already a creation method for single items `Observable.of(cached_data)`.

Comment: Also you can call `sub.complete()` after `sub.next()` to complete the observable which unsubscribe automatically on completion.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to fix this by keeping with the asynchronous style of my application. Instead of just returning my cache_data in an observable, I first wrap it in a Promise, which then gets wrapped in an observable.

```
let cacheFromPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(cache_data);
});

return Observable.fromPromise(cacheFromPromise);
```

Everything works perfectly now.

Comment: Do you know why this happens? I'm running into the exact same problem and doing what you did, turning a Promise into an Observable allows me to call `unsubscribe()` on it.

Comment: @KaMok This seems to happen when the Observable doesn't return anything, so the `sub` variable in my above example isn't yet defined. Wrapping it in a promise _forces_ it to be async, therefore giving `sub` time to be assigned a value

Comment: I used `Observable.of(true)`, as well as `Observable.create()` with like 3 lines of `.next(true)`, which returns `true`.